# Why can't I find a 'svg' element in a webpage with xpathcontaining a 'svg' element?

Tags: html, xpath

In a webpage containing the following piece of code:

```
...
<svg class="main-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1394" height="450" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%;">
<defs id="defs-a3c0aa">
<g class="clips">
<clipPath class="axesclip" id="clipa3c0aax">
<rect x="40" y="0" width="1274" height="450">
....
```

I use the 'Try XPath' extension to search for an xpath, and I try the following expression:

```
//svg
```

but no hit comes back. The number of found elements is zero. And there is NO iframe in that page somwhere.

So what could be going on? (I cannot post the page as it is not public)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You better use below xpath

```
//*:svg
```

it means all descendants having any namespace and its local-name is `svg`.

```
//*[local-name() = 'svg']
```

Above one also would work. Hope this helps...

Comment: I don’t know about how Selenium, specifically, handles this. But XPath in general does pay attention to namespace declarations.

Comment: You may try this ``//*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' or @*[namespace-uri()='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg']]`` too...i hope ths might work for you...

Answer (score 0):

The `<svg>` element has a namespace. You need to register the namespace with a prefix, and specify the prefix in XPath. For example, if you register the prefix `s` for `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg`, the XPath expression will become

```
//s:svg
```

The way how to register the namespace depends on what language you're using.